# Swift: How to access a CSV file in temporary directory (NSTemporaryDirectory()) after creating it?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a simple app that creates a csv file and saves it in a temporary directory. It seems to work but where or how can I access that file?

Below is the sample code that I use to create my csv file:

```
// CSV file creating
func creatCSV() -> Void {
    let fileName = "Example.csv"
    let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    let csvText = "Time,Date,Heartrate(BPM)\n"

    do {
        try csvText.write(to: path!, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to create file")
        print("\(error)")
    }
    print(path ?? "not found")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write to the file:

```
func createCSV() -> String? {
    let fileName = "Example.csv"
    let tempDir = NSTemporaryDirectory()
    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: tempDir, isDirectory: true).appendingPathComponent(fileName)

    let csvText = "Time,Date,Heartrate(BPM)\n"

    do {
        try csvText.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
        return fileURL.path 
    } catch {
        print("Failed to create file: \(error)")
        return nil
    }

}
```

To read from the file:

```
func readCSV(path:String) throws {
    let text = try String(contentsOfFile: path)
    print("I read the following from the file: \(text)")
}
```

Example using both:

```
if let path = createCSV() {
    print("Path was \(path)")
    try readCSV(path: path)
}
```

Comment: Better to return `URL?` instead of a path string.

Comment: And you should move the `return fileURL.path` to be inside the `do` block since it is part of the "success" code path.

Comment: @Mesquita.sra please accept the answer if it solves your issue.